# I want to turn this if formula into an array formula but cant seem to get it to auto populate down the rows

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

I want the driving distance between two address's and I am running a script that allows the following statement work.

This works but I have to drag the formula down when new rows are added from my mobile app into my sheet

```
=(IF(ISBLANK($AF2:$AF),"",DrivingMeters($E2:$E,$AF2:$AF)/1000))
```

This doesn't work

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($AF$2:$AF),"",DrivingMeters($E$2:$E,$AF$2:$AF)/1000))
```

I cant work out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: To clarify a bit more - the second formula returns the first distance in kilometers correctly and then copies that same distance down for every other address combination.

Comment: Please share your sheet

Answer (score 0):

it could possible be you need to adjust your DrivingMeters custom formula to accept arrays. Please share the sheet or custom formula

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AF2:AF="",, DrivingMeters(E2:E, AF2:AF)/1000))
```